# How to change view of expandable list view children when parent is collapsed in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-expandable-list-view

I am implementing a selection mode in `ExpandableListView`. The selection toggles when I click a child. I have a `CheckBox` in each parent, from which I want to control the selection of all the children at once.

My problem is that when the parent is collapsed and I click its `CheckBox`, the app crashes due to null pointer exception because when I try to change the selection of the children, I can't find the children and get null. But everything works fine when the parent is expanded.

So, what is a good approach to tackle such kind of problem?

Comment: Don't try to change the selection of the `CheckBox`. Your data model can have a boolean field called `isSelected`. When you want to check/uncheck all children, just change the boolean flag for all of them. then, on your `onBindViewHolder`, just say `checkBox.setChecked(item.isSelected())`

Comment: I want to change the selection in the calling fragment activity, and also I don't think if there is a `onBindViewHolder` method in `ExpandableListView`

Comment: oh sorry. I misunderstood. I thought you were using `RecyclerView` with expandable adapter. I suggest you use a library that handles all the things you need. I've personally used this myself before and it works very well - https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view#expandable-check-recyclerview

Comment: @ᴛʜᴇᴘᴀᴛᴇʟ the library you linked I think doesn't have checkboxes on the parent, while I have already implemented selections on children, I don't think that l need this library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by adding some lines of code without changing the previous code, so this answer may be helpful for someone who doesn't want to rewrite the code with a different approach.

In the calling `Fragment` or `Activity`, where the `Adapter` is being set, add:

```
private val isMyGroupExpanded = SparseBooleanArray()
```

```
val MyAdapterEV = AdapterEV(/* params */) { isChecked, groupPosition ->
    changeSelection(isChecked, groupPosition)
}
// record which groups are expanded and which are not
MyAdapterEV.setOnGroupExpandListener { i -> isMyGroupExpanded.put(i, true) }
MyAdapterEV.setOnGroupCollapseListener { i -> isMyGroupExpanded.put(i, false) }
```

```
// and where changing the selection of child
private fun changeSelection(isChecked: Boolean, groupPosition: Int) {
    if (isMyGroupExpanded.get(groupPosition, false)) { 
        /* change only if the group is expanded */ 
    }
}
```

So, the children of the collapsed group are not affected, but they are needed to be changed when the group expands, for that, add some lines of code in the `Adapter`:

```
private val isGroupChecked = SparseBooleanArray()
```

```
// inside override fun getGroupView(...
MyCheckBoxView.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
    onCheckedChangeListener(isChecked, groupPosition)
    isGroupChecked.put(groupPosition, isChecked)
}
```

```
// inside override fun getChildView(...
if (isGroupChecked.contains(groupPosition)) {
    myView.visibility = if (isGroupChecked.get(groupPosition)) View.VISIBLE else View.INVISIBLE
}
```